# fixed number of characters in a regex match

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Is there a way to match a fixed number of characters in a fixed length string via regex?

Example, I want to match all strings where the length of string is 5 and there are exactly 3 alphabets and 2 exclamations (!). The exclamations can be anywhere in the string.

Example matches: abc!!, a!b!c, !!abc, a!!bc

I tried to match using lookahead but I wasn't able to limit the length. The following was the regex I used.

```
(?=\w*!\w*!\w*)[\w!]{5}
```

This matches a!!!b and a!!!! as well which I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a lookahead based regular expression.

```
^(?=(?:\w*!){2}\w*$)[\w!]{5}$
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jE5xR0/4)

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to just specify all possibilities.

```
(?=\w\w\w!!|\w\w\!\w\!|\w\w\!!\w|\w!\w\w!|\w!\w!\w|\w!!\w\w|!\w!\w\w|!!\w\w\w)
```

Regex doesn't work well with combinations/permutations.

If the number of combinations is too large, do it in parts where the first regex gathers potential matches and the second (and beyond) continue to validate it.

```
[\w!]{5}
match.count('!') == 2
match.count('\w') == 3
```

(that isn't valid code -- just a concept)

Comment: Why not, but with this approach, do you believe that a lookahead is needed when you can use a simple non capturing group (with anchors). And for the second approach, you only need to count `!` since you can deduce the number of other characters.

Comment: For the first, I just took the original regex and modified it.  For the second, yes for this case.  As I said, it was just an example.